# YANG - leafref seems not to be working

Tags: model, constraints, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I would appreciate if a more yang experienced person could help me. 
I am triying to apply a constraint reference between 2 different lists, in the next way:

```
list company{
    key company-id;
    leaf company-id {
        type yang:uuid;
    }
}

list employee {
   key employee-id;
   leaf employee-id {
       type yang:uuid;
    }
    leaf company {
     type leafref {
         path "/company/company-id"; 
     }
  }
}
```

I am performing some tests with RESTCONF api, and I would like to check if it is possible to avoid a POST command, in order to create a new employee, if its related company is not created. I mean, I would like to use a yang model and include a referential constraint between the 2 lists.

I have tried using "must" statement as follows:

```
must "boolean(/company[company-id=current()]"
```

But there was no luck with that attempt.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to make it work. If you want that one list of your model has a foreign key reference with other second list, you have to include the field of type leafref in the key of the list. Using the example of my previous question:

Having the next list:

```
list company{
    key company-id;
    leaf company-id {
        type yang:uuid;
    }
}
```

If you want to include in the model other list, which will depend of company-id, you have to declare it with the next key:

```
list employee {   
  key "employee-id company";    

   leaf employee-id {
       type yang:uuid;
    }
    leaf company {
     type leafref {
         path "/company/company-id"; 
        } 
   }
 }
```

Pay attention to the key of the second list:

key "employee-id company";

I have tested it, and its working properly.

Thanks anyway to the people that have read my question.

Cheers, Julián

Comment: Including a leaf in the list's key makes it mandatory but it also enforces uniqueness. So now you can have one employee assigned to two companies. This situation would be represented by two entries in the employee list. Is this really what you want? Did you try to make the leaf `company` inside list `employee` mandatory explicitly? That would modify the original model to less extent.